# The number of bijective polynomials of particular degree in a field

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology, field-theory, permutations, irreducible-polynomials

I need to know please:

In a finite field of q elements how many bijective polynomials exist whose degree are smaller than d?

Comment: Sounds like a very tough question, when $d>3$. My copy of Lidl & Niederreiter is in my office, so I cannot check if the have anything related.

Comment: JyrkiLahtonen I give you the application which is related to crypto too. Consider one who defines a poly. $f_1$ on a field and evaluate at some points $X$ to obtain a set of values $Y$. To make the elements in $Y$ uniformly at random he picks a random bijective poly. of degree equal to smaller than degree of $f_1$. So, to prove this is secure he needs to know the number of random bijective poly. whose degrees are specified as above. –